Tourist visa of Switzerland for family members but German business visa for primary applicant
A resident Indian (father) is applying for a short stay visa to travel from India to Germany for an urgent business trip which is sponsored by his employer.
He is having a wife and 2 young kids (less than 6 years of age) in the family who are resident Indians. The family except father, plans to visit Switzerland, France and Germany for 27 days in total. All are traveling abroad for the first time. The father plans to join and visit places with them over the weekends. He will work at office during the weekdays. The employer of father is aware but doesn't want to endorse the plan with family. The husband and wife will cover the travel expenses.
The visa appointment slots are available for Germany and France under the tourist visa category but at a date later than the expected date of travel of father. So they didn't try for it. But appointment slots for Switzerland's Visa are available in the next 2 days. So they plan to apply for a short stay single entry (tourist) Visa for the family members except father at the Switzerland Consulate via VFS.
The family plans to travel all 4 members together at least at the start of the trip. And may travel together at the end of trip back to India. So family plans to book flight from India to Germany and return as well so that it is inline with the employer.
Came to know through friends that the family members except father should stay more number of days in Switzerland than any other country.
Now the questions are:

What important points should be mentioned in the cover letter for Visa appointment of each applicant?
How can this trip be planned well considering the above situation?
What are the important points to consider for Visa, bookings and travel?


How long is the intended trip? One point to consider is that since the rest of the family wouldn’t be planning their trip if the father’s business trip wasn’t happening, evidence of the father’s visa being approved will need to be submitted with the applications from the rest of the family. Also to consider how having the entire family travel may weaken proof of ties to India.

All 4 members of the family will travel for 27 days. The place of departure from India and arrival to India is same for each member. However different flight as father's booking is done by employer but all other's personally.

One key thing to note in visa applications is you have to be boring as possible. Should be just another person applying for visa, nothing stands out. Your issue is bit complicated. Just mention in cover letter what you said here (minus why you choose Switzerland).
Also, note that you have to stay in Switzerland for more than half of your time, while your father has to stay more than half of the time in Germany. Make sure your hotel bookings reflect that. General suggestions can be found in other answers.
